# Group Json Array to Jquery Objects

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON Array like this.

```
{"records":[{"ColorId":"3","ColorName":"Red","GenderId":"3","GenderName":"Female","SizeId":"1","SizeName":"N\/A"},{"ColorId":"2","ColorName":"Green","GenderId":"2","GenderName":"Male","SizeId":"1","SizeName":"N\/A"},{"ColorId":"3","ColorName":"Red","GenderId":"2","GenderName":"Male","SizeId":"1","SizeName":"N\/A"}]}
```

I need to separate these variables into separate objects with distinct

> Color : ColorId,ColorName
>
> Gender : GenderId,GenderName
>
> Size: SizeId,SizeName

Comment: which json library you are using?

Comment: i have just used jquery

Comment: please tell me, what is a `json library`, @KalpenPatel?

Comment: If you want to do using jquery than we can do it using JSON.parse("your json string"). and than you have write code to get data from it. once you parse json data using JSON.parse it will return json object. and using it you can find length of data using object.length in jquery. and from it you can retrieve data from your json

Comment: Then you talk about a `javascript library`, not a `json library`, @KalpenPatel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a simple `loop` of the `recods` and creating your data in an own structure. There is even no need to use of any jQuery functions.

```
for( var i = 0, l = data.records.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    color.push({ColorId: data.records[i].ColorId, ColorName: data.records[i].ColorName});
    gender.push({GenderId: data.records[i].GenderId, GenderName: data.records[i].GenderName});
    size.push({SizeId: data.records[i].SizeId, SizeName: data.records[i].SizeName});
}
```

**[Wokring example.](https://jsfiddle.net/ufjk5j80/)**

Comment: Thanks!. It Works , But i need those to be distinct too ,, how can i get that to work

Comment: Assuming the `IDs` are unique, the easiest way would be to switch from `array` to an `object` and just use the `id` as `property`, so it would be distinct: https://jsfiddle.net/ufjk5j80/1/ @HudhaifaYoosuf